# Issues on wrong date format in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

If I give wrong date in one block field it should not allowed to enter other block in oracle forms.

eg:-  in date field I'm entering values like `MUHUTHUTHU` after that I'm moving cursor to next block. first time I'm getting an error mesage `FRM-50026` (wrong date format)  but the cursor  moved to other block.

But I don't want to allow to another block. Thanks to help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the format mask property of that item as a valid date format (MM/DD/RRRR for example), Forms should take care of it by itself.

If not, you need to check the date format in the WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger and if it's not a valid date then raise the FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE exception:

```
RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
```

That will keep the cursor in that field.

Comment: But when-validate-item is not firing, i'm getting an error message message 'frm-50026' before that. Can you tell me which format i have to write in when-validate-item trigger?

Comment: If I set the format mask property of the date item, Forms won't let me moved to another item unless the item is null or has a proper date value. I usually use the DD/MM/RRRR format, because that's how we write dates in Spanish but you can use whatever format you need.

Answer (score 1):

The default functionality if the entered data is not valid according to the format mask is that the focus stays in the item. It is though possible to accidently or not override the default functionality. You can e.g. use On-Error trigger to override the default error handling and of you forget to call RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE after your custom error handling then the program flow will continue as no error have happen at all.